# How to avoid session expired cookie for Owin Federation authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, owin, federation

We are using Cookie and WsFederation middleware to authenticate against ADFS server. Everything is working fine except the generate cookie is always session expired.

When user close and reopen browser, they need to relogin.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieDomain = "...some domain..."
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AdfsMetadataAddress],
            Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppWtRealm],
            UseTokenLifetime = false
        });
```

What are the things that we need to do in order to make cookie persisted in browser side?

Thanks very much in advance~

Answer (score 1):

Add a CookieAuthenticationProvider where you can set the expiration

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieDomain = "...some domain...",
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnResponseSignIn = context =>
            {
                context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
                context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think the CookieDomain is strictly necessary.